# Node Error - Not allowed to load local resource

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I am making a chat app with socket.io. When I want to pull the client file it gives me this error:

> Not allowed to load local
>   resource:file:///C:/%20/Users/x/Desktop/Node%20Code/Chat%20Bot/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js

My html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Chat App</title>
    <script src="file:///C: \Users\x\Desktop\Node Code\Chat Bot\node_modules\socket.io-client\dist\socket.io.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>


  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to load a resource outside of the project directory or from a user level directory, hence you get the error "cannot access local resource error".

Place the file in the root folder of your project and then try to reference it. It will work

Comment: So could I copy the js file the folder?

Comment: Ya, copy it in the root folder

Comment: @ellipsis You saved my day bro